# UUID-Generator in QField

Tags: qgis, qfield

I have a QGIS project running on QField that allows the user to draw points/lines and assign attributes to them. Every point/line gets an unique ID that get created through an UUID-Generator in QGIS.

**When I open the project on QField, no ID is created and the ID is blank.** How can I achieve an unique ID when I create objects using QField?

Comment: Have you checked that you have a correct data type in your field? UUID requires string field.

Comment: yes, I have a string field for the id. the uuid generator works in qgis but does not work in qfield.

Comment: Maybe You have to assign a default value to the id field using the uuid() function. This should work in Qfield as well.